# ViewChangeEvent not triggered in a view that is contained in a TabSheet

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

In my Vaadin 8 application, I have a `TabSheet`, that contains several views. When I override the enter method in the first view of my `TabSheet`, and then I proceed to enter the view on my application, the method doesn't get called.

Comment: You should supply a code example so people can better understand what you're trying to achieve. You should also specify which exact Vaadin version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a Navigator, and have you registered the views for it? Navigator's `navigateTo` is what calls the `enter`. Registering views happens along these lines:

```
navigator.addView("", new InitialView());
navigator.addView("second", new SecondView());
```

Navigation also updates the URI fragment in your browser, and makes it possible to bookmark specific views and enter them via direct URL. See e.g. https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator for more information about Navigator.

TabSheet isn't the most trivial thing to use with Navigator and I'm afraid I don't have a ready-made example at hand, but I think it should be doable with a custom ViewDisplay and maybe SelectedTabChangeListener.

If you aren't interested in the Navigator approach, I suppose you could replace the View+`enter` with something along these lines, although if you need to know the previously selected tab you'll need to keep track of it yourself since this particular event isn't very informative:

```
tabSheet.addSelectedTabChangeListener(e -> {
    ((MyClass) tabSheet.getSelectedTab()).myMethod());
});
```